# Problem with groupby tabel Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Sample of my dataset is like that:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({"Sex":["male", "male", "male", "female", "female"],
                   "Housing":["rent", "rent", "own", "own", "rent"],
                  "Saving accounts":[1000, 1200, 3000, 4000, 5600],
                  "Checking account":[1200, 1540, 6780, 2000, 3000]})
```

I have code like below:

```
data.groupby(['Sex', 'Housing']).agg({'Saving accounts':[min, max, np.mean, np.median, sum],
                          'Checking account':[min, max, np.mean, np.median, sum]})
```

I would like to achieve table which will show me basic statistics like: min, max etc. based on Sex and housing fo example: male who housing is own hase min saving accounts for example 1000 and max 6000 and min checking account 2000 and max 5000 and the same about mean and median.
I want to have something like this: (example of course about other data)

[image]

Nevertheless, I have an Error:

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

What should I do ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is column(s) are not numeric.

So try cast to integers or floats:

```
cols = ['Saving accounts', 'Checking account']
data[cols] = data[cols].astype(int)
#data[cols] = data[cols].astype(float)
```

And if failed because some non numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert not parseable values to missing values:

```
cols = ['Saving accounts', 'Checking account']
data[cols] = data[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```